# converting xml to java objects with xstream in java

Tags: java, xstream

I have an xml ans i want to make it objects , i am using xsteam for this and I have added xstream jars in my classpath..

below is my xml...

```
<Eurexflows xmlns:eur="http://www.eurexchange.com/EurexIRSFullInventoryReport" xmlns:fpml="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation">
<EurexMessageObject>
<CCPTradeId>109599</CCPTradeId>
<novDateTime>2012-02-15 10:59:00.0</novDateTime>
</EurexMessageObject>
<EurexMessageObject>
<CCPTradeId>122270</CCPTradeId>
<novDateTime>2012-06-29 18:59:00.0</novDateTime>
</EurexMessageObject>
</Eurexflows>
```

below is my pojo...

```
public class EurexMessageObject {

    private Long CCPTradeId;
    private String migratedDate;

    public Long getCCPTradeId() {
        return CCPTradeId;
    }

    public void setCCPTradeId(Long cCPTradeId) {
        CCPTradeId = cCPTradeId;
    }

    public String getMigratedDate() {
        return migratedDate;
    }

    public void setMigratedDate(String migratedDate) {
        this.migratedDate = migratedDate;
    }


}
```

and in my main class I have coded this way..

```
String xmlInputtra="C:\\Rahul\\InputXml\\Xmloutput.xml";
         try
         {

      // get XStream instance and set required aliases
            XStream xstream = new XStream();
            xstream.alias("EurexMessageObject", com.rbos.gdspc.eurex.EurexMessageObject.class);
            // prepare cash flow message from xslt output
            EurexMessageObject eurexflowMsg = (EurexMessageObject) xstream.fromXML(xmlInputtra);
            System.out.println(eurexflowMsg.toString());

         }catch(Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

now upon debuging I am getting the following exception..please advise how can I overcome from this

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not C (position: START_DOCUMENT seen C... @1:1)
```

Comment: You should put in the var `xmlInputtra` a xml not a path.

Answer (score 2):

Well,the thing that is overlooked here is how you are **reading** in the XML file.you are using the  method **fromXML** which is expecting the actual **XML input** and not the **file name**. So when it parses your xml (which is "Xmloutput.xml" not the actual xml)

I suggest you to use a **FileReader/BufferedReader** in order to get the contents of the XML back. Something like this should work:

```
XStream instream = new XStream();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Xmloutput.xml"));
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
   buff.append(line);
}
EurexMessageObject eurexflowMsg = (EurexMessageObject)instream.fromXML(buff.toString());
```

I hope it will help you, best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Here path for XML file:

```
String xmlInputtra="C:\\Rahul\\InputXml\\Xmloutput.xml";
```

is treated as XML contents,
so you need to pass as String for that you can read file and pass to constructor.